# MvxAppCompatDialogFragment cancellation via Back button is not completely working

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Closing a `MvxAppCompatDialogFragment` via the back button doesn't seem to work completely. The button I clicked to trigger the dialog remains disabled after the dialog is dismissed. It's almost like the `Task` is stuck. If I change to `MvxDialogFragment` then the back button will close the dialog as expected, and the button I clicked to trigger the dialog is enabled again after the dialog is dismissed. I'm trying to use `MvxAppCompatDialogFragment` because I'm using `MvxAppCompatActivity`. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in MvvmCross 5.2.1?

Here is the ViewModel:

```
public class ConfirmationViewModel : MvxViewModel<ConfirmationConfiguration, bool?>, IMvxLocalizedTextSourceOwner
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _mvxNavigationService;

    public ConfirmationViewModel(IMvxNavigationService mvxNavigationService)
    {
        _mvxNavigationService = mvxNavigationService;
    }

    public override void Prepare([NotNull] ConfirmationConfiguration parameter)
    {
        if (parameter == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parameter));
        Title = parameter.Title;
        Body = parameter.Body;
        PositiveCommandText = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.YesCommandText) 
            ? parameter.YesCommandText 
            : LocalizedTextSource.GetText("Yes");
        NegativeCommandText = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.NoCommandText)
            ? parameter.NoCommandText
            : LocalizedTextSource.GetText("No");
    }

    private bool? _confirmationResult;
    public bool? ConfirmationResult
    {
        get => _confirmationResult;
        private set => SetProperty(ref _confirmationResult, value);
    }

    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get => _title;
        set => SetProperty(ref _title, value);
    }

    private string _body;
    public string Body
    {
        get => _body;
        set => SetProperty(ref _body, value);
    }

    private string _positiveCommandText;
    public string PositiveCommandText
    {
        get => _positiveCommandText;
        set => SetProperty(ref _positiveCommandText, value);
    }

    private string _negativeCommandText;
    public string NegativeCommandText
    {
        get => _negativeCommandText;
        set => SetProperty(ref _negativeCommandText, value);
    }

    private IMvxAsyncCommand _yesCommand;
    public IMvxAsyncCommand PositiveCommand => _yesCommand ?? (_yesCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(OnPositiveCommandAsync));

    private async Task OnPositiveCommandAsync()
    {
        ConfirmationResult = true;
        await _mvxNavigationService.Close(this, ConfirmationResult);
    }

    private IMvxAsyncCommand _noCommand;
    public IMvxAsyncCommand NegativeCommand => _noCommand ?? (_noCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(OnNegativeCommandAsync));

    private async Task OnNegativeCommandAsync()
    {
        ConfirmationResult = false;
        await _mvxNavigationService.Close(this, ConfirmationResult);
    }

    public IMvxLanguageBinder LocalizedTextSource => new MvxLanguageBinder("", GetType().Name);

    public IMvxLanguageBinder TextSource => LocalizedTextSource;
}

public class ConfirmationConfiguration
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string YesCommandText { get; set; }
    public string NoCommandText { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the View:

```
[MvxDialogFragmentPresentation(Cancelable = true)]
[Register(nameof(ConfirmationFragment))]
public class ConfirmationFragment : MvxAppCompatDialogFragment<ConfirmationViewModel>
{
    public ConfirmationFragment()
    {
        RetainInstance = true;
    }

    public ConfirmationFragment(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
        RetainInstance = true;
    }

    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity)
            .SetTitle(ViewModel.Title)
            .SetMessage(ViewModel.Body)
            .SetPositiveButton(ViewModel.PositiveCommandText, OnPositiveButton)
            .SetNegativeButton(ViewModel.NegativeCommandText, OnNegativeButton);
        return builder.Create();
    }

    private async void OnNegativeButton(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewModel.NegativeCommand.CanExecute())
        {
            await ViewModel.NegativeCommand.ExecuteAsync();
        }
    }

    private async void OnPositiveButton(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewModel.PositiveCommand.CanExecute())
        {
            await ViewModel.PositiveCommand.ExecuteAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm navigating to the dialog like this:

```
        var confirmation = await Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNavigationService>().Navigate<ConfirmationViewModel, ConfirmationConfiguration, bool?>(
            new ConfirmationConfiguration()
            {
                Body = "Hello, World!",
                Title = "Testing"
            });
```

If I change the base class from `MvxAppCompatDialogFragment` to `MvxDialogFragment` then it all works as expected.

Comment: I guess you use the `MvxAppCompatPresenter` as well? I've got to look into this, because the test project also just uses the `MvxDialogFragment` see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/TestProjects/Playground/Playground.Droid/Views/ModalView.cs

Comment: Yes, I'm using the `MvxAppCompatPresenter`. It's being brought in by  `MvxAppCompatSetup`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was indeed an issue in MvvmCross v5.2.1 (thanks for reporting!). As a workaround for now you can add this code in your DialogFragment class:

```
public override void OnCancel(IDialogInterface dialog)
{
    base.OnCancel(dialog);
    ViewModel?.ViewDestroy();
}

public override void DismissAllowingStateLoss()
{
    base.DismissAllowingStateLoss();
    ViewModel?.ViewDestroy();
}

public override void Dismiss()
{
    base.Dismiss();
    ViewModel?.ViewDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've looked into this. What happens is that when you press the back button it closes the View without calling the `NavigationSerivce.Close()`. This prevents the result `Task` to be called and  either set or cancel the action. I'm not sure if this is a bug or just behavior. A workaround could be to call `Close` from `ConfirmationViewModel` `ViewDissapearing`, or cancel the `Task` yourself.

Comment: I don't think that's a good workaround. Calling `Close` from `ViewDisappearing` will make it so the dialog never survives screen rotation. If I bring the dialog up, then rotate the device then `ViewDisappearing` is called. This is another thing I expected the framework to handle but it's not. I have a `DialogFragment` shown with `RetainInstance` set to `true` but it gets closed for good when I rotate the device. That shouldn't happen.

Comment: Could you open an issue for that?